# entering a value in a text box using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I started to learn python selenium but I have a simple problem that I can't Understand it ...
It can open site but can't write anything in any boxes ...
It just open the site ...

what's the problem ???

Search field name is"q"

```
<input id="id-search-field" name="q" type="search" role="textbox" class="search-field placeholder" placeholder="Search" value="" tabindex="1">
```

and the code is :

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


driver = Chrome("C://chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("http://www.python.org")


elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.send_keys("selenium")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found it ...
it was because of my webdriver version ...

sorry I don't know how to delete my topic ...

Comment: Under the tags on your question there is `share edit close delete flag`. You can delete using that link, if you wish

Comment: You don't have to **delete** your question, just delete this comment and ***answer*** your own question with what steps you took to fix your problem and accept your own answer. :)

Comment: As @PixelEinstein mentioned you can answer your own question. Edit this answer  with the exact steps you have taken to solve your question and come back after 48 hours to accept the answer as a solution to your question